# How to update calendar?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, navigator, daypilot

I'm using DayPilot Calendar and Navigator on Visual Studios 2013, webform.

I am able to link the navigator to the calendar, so when I click on a different week, it reflects on the calendar as well.

Problem is, when i select a different week, all my data in the calendar is gone, and the week I click on is not updated in the calendar.

I tried changing the properties for the Calendar to postback/callback but it still doesn't work.

However, my Navigator is able to retain the data when I select a different week.

[image: This is when]

This is when i first debug the webform.
[image]

And this is when i click on the Navigator (the calendar at the bottom). As shown, the data is gone.

How do i solve this problem?

-- You can see that the navigator retains the data shown by the date in bold.

These are the codes I've used.

> ```
> protected void DayPilotCalendar1_Command (object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.CommandEventArgs e)
> {  
>     switch (e.Command)
>     {
>         case "navigate":
>         DateTime start = (DateTime)e.Data["EventStart"];
>         DateTime end = (DateTime) e.Data["EventEnd"];
>         DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = start;
>         DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
>         DayPilotCalendar1.Update();
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload the event data as well:

```
protected void DayPilotCalendar1_Command (object sender, DayPilot.Web.Ui.Events.CommandEventArgs e)
{  
    switch (e.Command)
    {
        case "navigate":
        DateTime start = (DateTime)e.Data["EventStart"];
        DateTime end = (DateTime) e.Data["EventEnd"];
        DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = start;
        DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = LoadYourEventsHere(); // load data
        DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
        DayPilotCalendar1.Update();
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the missing part:

```
DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = LoadYourEventsHere(); // load data
```